# Converting numeric time (minutes or hours) to time format (HH:MM) in R

Tags: r, time

I have a simple, but tricky question in R. How do I convert numeric values given in "minutes" or "hours" to time format in HH:MM? I have been looking for solutions, but not yet found one.

Let's say I have a vector c(100, 563, 210), and my desired output would be "1:40, 9:23, 3:30", since the numbers in the vector are given in minutes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sprintf`:

```r
sprintf("%.02d:%.02d", mns %/% 60, round(mns %% 60))
#[1] "01:40" "09:23" "03:30"
```

---

Longer, but within the `lubridate` package, you can do:

```r
library(lubridate)
mns <- dminutes(c(100, 563, 210)) %>% 
  seconds_to_period()
#1] "1H 40M 0S" "9H 23M 0S" "3H 30M 0S"

sprintf('%02d:%02d', hour(mns), minute(mns))
#[1] "01:40" "09:23" "03:30"
```

Comment: Maël one more thing: how can I add something like na.rm=T, so to disregard NA and NaN values? I have a vector that contains NaN, and thus the function is cut with the error saying there is NaN.

Comment: You could remove them in the first place. `na.omit` for instance

Comment: that is a way, sure, but those rows have other valuable data, in spite of having NaN in some columns. Never mind, I changed them to 0.